# wordpress login form

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm finally getting into wordpress, and I'm a bit confused by how it works.

Can someone give me an example of how to just allow a user to login/register?

(This question in specific I'm more interested in not ending up at the control panel)

As in, a very simple form to login on the main page without being forced to go to that wordpress login screen.

Comment: Try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where questions like yours are very common: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/membership

Answer (score 1):

check out, [peters login redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)

this lets you login and sends you back to what ever page you want

[image: peters login redirect options]

this plugin along with [sidebar login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/) will work quite well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### For login:

There is the [Sidebar Login plugin](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/) that includes a widget that you can add to your sidebar.

[image]

> Sidebar-Login has both a widget and a template tag to allow you to
>   have a login form in the sidebar of your wordpress powered blog.
>
> It lets users login, and then redirects them back to the page they
>   logged in from rather than the backend, it also shows error messages.